(x86_64 NASM) Why is my program returning 0 instead of 256?
This is my first assembly code:
;program name - first.asm
section .data ;stores initialised var

section .bss  ;stores uninit var

section .text  ;actual code
global _start

_start:
  mov eax,1
  mov ebx,256
  int 0x80

ebx is a 32-bit register, and from what I understood, eax=1 is syscall for program termination, and it returns the value stored in ebx. But when I ran the program, it's returning 0. Why is there an overflow?
#run.bash
#!/bin/bash

nasm -felf64 $1.asm
ld $1.o -o $1
./$1
echo $?
rm -rf $1.o $1

in the terminal I ran sh run.bash first, and it returned 0 instead of 256.

Linux exit code is 8 bits.

@interjay so it'll return the value in bl instead of ebx? and similarly instead of mov eax,1 I can write mov al,1?

You can't use mov al, 1 because then the rest of eax might have the wrong value.

See also man exit, in particular: "the least significant byte of status (i.e., status & 0xFF) is returned to the parent"

Note, unrelated, but you generally want the bss section first. It's not wrong the way you having it, but traditionally "block started by symbol" was the first section.

@DavidC.Rankin: You're talking about source order?  Where does that tradition come from?  I don't remember hearing about it.  I tend to put .data and .bss after .text, in small / toy programs for experimenting with something.  (Partly because that matches the binary layout from the default linker script; .bss is extra bytes / pages at the end of .data that are zero-filled instead of backed by file data)

@PeterCordes - there is no reference for it. I recall it from a professor back in the 80's. Other than that there are just general references to it such as shown at .bss.

@DavidC.Rankin: That wikipedia article doesn't mention anything about asm source order, and the diagram showing address layout has a conventional layout like Linux uses, with the BSS after the end of .data.  (Note the stack at the top growing downward).  Sounds like just a coding-style recommendation from a specific professor, which might work well for some people or some projects.
